# How to pass data(count) from Quantity component to Mainpart component using lifting state up in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pass-data

Quantity component is my child class and Mainpart component is my parent class.i want to use my (count) in my parent class.but i dont know how to pass that data.sorry my english is not good.i think you will get the idea.

const MainPart = () => {

```
const submit = (event) => {
    debugger;
    event.preventDefault();

}

return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={4}>
                        <Picture image='../images/test.jpg' alt='tent' />
                    </Col>
                    <Col sm={8}>
                        <Title title='4 Person tent' itemNo='Item No.  MA000001' />
                        <Currency mark='$' price='150.00' />
                        <Quantity />
                        <div style={{ marginTop: '5%', textAlign: 'center' }}>
                            <input type='submit' value='ADD TO CART' style={{ backgroundColor: 'yellow', padding: '5px 5px 5px 5px' }} />
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </form>

    </div>
);
```

};

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

const Quantity = (props) => {
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

```
const increaseClick = () => {
    
    setCount(count + 1 ) 
}

const decreaseClick = () => {
   
    setCount(count - 1 ) 
}

return (
    <>
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', marginTop: '5%', marginLeft: '30%' }}>
            <Button variant="primary" style={{ marginRight: '5%' }} onClick={decreaseClick}>-</Button>
            <h3>{count}</h3>
            <Button variant="primary" style={{ marginLeft: '5%' }} onClick={increaseClick}>+</Button>
        </div>
        
    </>
);
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your state in parent and then pass to child, it will work.

```
const MainPart = () => {
   const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

   return (
     ...Your rest of code.
     <Quantity count={count} setCount={setCount} />
   )
}
```

Then In your child component, Use like this:

```
const Quantity = ({ count, setCount }) => {
  const increaseClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1 ) 
  }
  const decreaseClick = () => {
    setCount(count - 1 ) 
  }

return (
 <>
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', marginTop: '5%', marginLeft: '30%' 
  }}>
        <Button variant="primary" style={{ marginRight: '5%' }} onClick={decreaseClick}>-</Button>
        <h3>{count}</h3>
        <Button variant="primary" style={{ marginLeft: '5%' }} onClick={increaseClick}>+</Button>
    </div>
    
  </>
);
}
```